# What kind of UPS do I need?

Tags: power-supply, ups

I've been looking into different kinds of UPS solutions. (Standby, Line-Interactive, Standby-Ferro, Double Conversion, and Delta Conversion UPSs) So far I think I've narrowed it down to Double Conversion or Line-Interactive. However, I'm unable to determine which of them is able to:

- Supplement power to accommodate watt spikes as equipment starts/stops.
- Charge as it supplies power to equipment when watt use is down.

**Which UPS type, if any, will fulfill these two requirements?**

And if I could venture a closely related question...

**Could such a UPS prevent a circuit breaker from tripping on a highly utilized circuit?**

Comment: There are many other questions on StackExchange about UPS. It's hardware related, and an integral component of high availability systems. No specific recommendation for an UPS solution was requested. Rather, the kind of UPS needed to solve a more broad problem. Anyone trying to fit "just one more server" on their circuit would ask a similar question. Please remove the off-topic hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically possible that both UPS's could do this if specifically designed to, but I would hazard that most are not designed to do this.   (Note that "watt spikes" is probably less accurate a term then current spikes, but I guess they are the same thing, if we assume that the voltage is constant - equipment won't generally cause an increase in voltage).

Generally a UPS requires MORE current on the input then on the output for 2 reasons - (1) to charge the battery and (2) to take into account inefficiencies of the UPS components.   I would speculate that a double conversion UPS would be more likely to handle this eventuality as the input and output are at least somewhat decoupled - on the flip side they are generally less efficient.

Comment: Is there a feature name to look for that would indicate this capability?

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm not sure it exists.   I am not an electrical engineer, but I seem to recall that there are circuits which  do "current limiting" or "current clamping".  It occurs to me that if you can find one (or more likely get one built - it should not be _that_ expensive (depending on the maximum current), if you put this before an Online (double conversion) UPS, the device would prevent to much current being drawn and the UPS should, in theory, provide the deficit.

Comment: Another approach might be purchase a battery charger, battery and inverter, and "make your own" UPS which would have this feature - ie the charge speed would be dictated by the charger, and the inverter could be specced larger then the charger because the battery is handling this.  Probably not a good idea for larger systems though.

Comment: Thanks @davidgo! I'm might DIY this after all. I have a remote site with a shared circuit and limited load availability. I'm just running some basic gear, but don't want to trip the breaker in this sensitive environment...

Comment: If going the DIY route, remember that (to the first order approximation - I'm ignoring the difference between Watt and VA, which can be 30%),  Watts=Current x Voltage, so a large car battery charger which can charge at say 12 volt, 10 amp is only able to provide 120 watts to the battery.  Of-course if you get 12 volt batteries, wire them in series, and get a charger capable of 24 volts you get 240 watts - of-course you then need an inverter which can take 24 volts input...

Comment: And suppose I've got a device expecting 120 volts with max wattage of 136? Do I _need_ 5 batteries in series? It's a motor, so I _think_ it will work, albeit slower with less power...

Comment: You dont want to power a motor off a UPS/invertor if you can avoid it because the inrush (startup) current is typically 2-3 times operational current, neaning the inverter should bee to be 500 watts+

Comment: The number of batteries you need is a function of the amp hours of the battery - you probably only need 1. Theoretically you should be able to power this off a 12 volt, 20 amp charger, with 1 x 12 volt sealed lead acid battery and a 500 watt inverter.

Comment: If you get a 12 volt, 7ah battery it can provide 84 watt hours, so it should last in the order of 30 mins for your load. A 14ah battery should last an hour or so.

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea of 5 batteries in series. You dont want to do that because you would need to handle 60 volts DC, and you would need a 60 volt charger

Comment: Was thinking 5x24=120. Device normally runs on 120 volts... I'm a cyber security guy and not the best at circuitry...

Comment: Also, you cant generally power a 120volt (AC) motor off DC power. You need an inverter to bring it back to AC

Comment: That would explain the giant brick that came with the motor device...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88718/discussion-between-primohacker-and-davidgo).